# Falha na segurança (PHP, JS, API, MYSQL)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, api

Fiz um site com login, cadastro e etc. Validei o login e o cadastro com método POST,o site tá no servidor e tudo, mas quando eu coloco o link da url já de dentro da página ele carrega. É algum erro que eu possa ter feito ou isso é "normal"?

LOGIN

```
<form name="formulario" id="formEnvia" action="valida.php" method="POST">

                        <label >CPF*</label>

                        <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="000.000.000-00" maxlength="14" pattern="\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}"
  title="Digite o CPF no formato nnn.nnn.nnn-nn" required />
                <br>
                        <label inputemail>E-mail*:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="SeuEmail@Email.com" maxlength="50" required/>

                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="valida_envio()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            Acessar</button>

                    </form>
```

VALIDAÇÃO DE LOGIN:

```
<?php


require_once "conexao.php";

$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cpf = '$cpf' AND email = '$email'";

$querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) <=0){
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email ou cpf incorretos.');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
    die();
}else if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0 ){
    setcookie("login", $cpf);
    header("Location:Postagem.html");
}
```

Comment: Como assim? Você pega uma url sem passar pelo login e ele entra? É isso?

Comment: Exatamente!!! Coloco a url e mesmo sem login ele entra no site

Comment: Hmmmm, então realmente tem falha de segurança. Você tá validando se existe alguma Session pra poder permitir a entrada no site? Como você tá fazendo o login? Se possível, edite o seu post e coloque o código.

Comment: Sim. Fiz a validação com o PHP pra pegar do bd do mysql. Também fiz um cadastro pra inserir os dados na bd, e todos com metodo post

Comment: Show, mas tipo, como você tá validando se um usuário logou? Pelo que entendi, você já fez a validação pra ver se existe o usuário no banco, certo? Mas isso não vai impedir alguém de chamar a url interna sem passar pelo login e entrar no site. O que você precisa fazer é validar se o usuário logou, utilizando Session. Por isso queria ver o seu código do login, pra ver o que você fez e se precisa adicionar algo...

Comment: Pronto. Editei a pergunta e coloquei os códigos, se puder dar uma olhada...

Comment: Tranquilo, vou editar nas respostas...

Comment: Mas pera ae... a página `Postagem.html` tem alguma restrição de acesso?

Comment: Não... como consigo fazer isso?

Comment: Uma coisa, se você ta mexendo com php, não utiliza html não, utiliza o arquivo .php que você será muito mais maleabilidade na hora de implementar algum código, porque você poderá utilizar os códigos da linguagem de acordo com a necessidade

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o código, tá faltando você utilizar a session e validar na página se a session existe, e se existir, você permite o usuário passar.

NT: Você precisa startar a session antes de tudo, afim de poder setar os valores, utilizando esse método **session_start()**. Ou seja, vá no seu primeiro arquivo php que é chamado e coloca esse método lá.

NT2: 
[Recomendo a leitura sobre sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), 
[Sobre restrição de acesso em PHP](https://www.devmedia.com.br/php-sistema-de-login-com-niveis-de-acesso/37217)

**Exemplo:**

Considerando que é a primeira página (login.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

    <form name="formulario" id="formEnvia" action="valida.php" method="POST">

                    <label >CPF*</label>

                    <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="000.000.000-00" maxlength="14" pattern="\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}"
                            title="Digite o CPF no formato nnn.nnn.nnn-nn" required />
                    <br>
                    <label inputemail>E-mail*:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="SeuEmail@Email.com" maxlength="50" required/>

                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="valida_envio()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        Acessar</button>
    </form>
```

Considerando que você já fez a requisição pelo post e passou os dados

```
        <?php

        require_once "conexao.php";

        $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
        $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cpf = '$cpf' AND email = '$email'";

        $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) <=0){
            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email ou cpf 
                 incorretos.');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
            die();
        }
        else if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0 ){//aqui você ta redirecionando pra página postagem, certo?                

            //editado
            //setando os valores nas sessions
            //NT: você precisa startar a session antes de tudo,
            $_SESSION["email "] = $email;
            $_SESSION["cpf "] = $cpf;

            //setcookie("login", $cpf);

            header("Location:Postagem.php");//depois de mudar

        }
```

Considerando que você ta na pagina Postagem.php

```
         <?php
             //isset verifica se a variável existe
             if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['cpf'])) {
         ?>
                    //conteudo da página aqui
                    <h1>página postagem</h1>

         <?php
              }
              else {
                   //redirecionar pra página login se não existir session
                   header('Location: index.php');
              }
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69007/discussion-between-marcio-cristian-and-nazare-lisboa).

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver assim:

Conectando ao banco de dados:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "portal");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar!, Motivo: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Validando login:

```
  <?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['valida'])){
  $cpf = $_REQUEST['cpf'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cpf = '$cpf' AND email = '$email'";

         $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

         if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) == 0){
             echo "Erro ao logar";
         }else {

           $_SESSION['cpf'] = $cpf;
           $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
         header("Location:postagem.php");
       }
}
```

Minha página index (login):

Eu começo com : 
`<?php session_start(); include 'config/conexao.php'; ?>`

Esse é o diretório onde salvei minha conexão com o bd.

E no final do código eu coloco :

`<?php include 'config/valida.php' ?>`
Que é onde salvei os códigos que eu validei o login.

Na minha página do site eu começo com:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['cpf']) && (!isset($_SESSION['email']))) {
  header("Location: ../index.php");
}

 ?>
```

Logo depois da tag `<body>` eu coloco:

```
<?php

                   $secao_cpf = $_SESSION['cpf'];
                   $secao_email   = $_SESSION['email'];

                  ?>
```

E logo depois do botão de "sair" eu coloco:

```
<?php
                               if (isset($_REQUEST['sair'])) {
                                 session_destroy();
                                 header ("Location:index.php");
                               }
                              ?>
```

Assim ninguém consegue entrar no site diretamente pelo link, só entra agora quem fizer o login correto.

Comment: Desculpe, mas tenho que alerta-la, o seu código não é seguro, da maneira que esta não parece validar a 'sessão', fora que não tem escape no mysql

Comment: Estranho...sempre que coloco o link direto para o página inicial ele nao vai, fica sempre voltando pro login.  escape? Poderia me explicar? Sou leiga em bd

Comment: Então Nazera, tem muitos problemas na sua solução, não tem como com um comentário eu explicar, mas pretendo formular uma resposta assim que possivel explicando os detalhes e sugerindo um exemplo pratico de entender, salvei sua pergunta nos favoritos para não esquecer.

Comment: Ta certo. Aguardo sua resposta